# How to set `You and moderator can reply` in bot when posting proactive message to channels?

Tags: javascript, next.js, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I am currently developing a bot that posts proactive message to channels. My client wants me to set `No reply` or `You and moderator can reply` on the message that posted from the bot proactively.

What I tried so far:

```js
// post message to channels
const credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(process.env.MicrosoftAppId, process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword);
const client = new ConnectorClient(credentials, { baseUri: serviceUrl });
const message = MessageFactory.text(inMessage);

let approveResult = false;
let MessageActivityId = "";

const conversationParams = {
    isGroup: true,
    bot: {
        id: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
        name: process.env.BotName
    },
    conversationType: 'channel',
    channelData: {
        channel: {
            id: teamsChannelId
        }
    },
    activity: message
};

const msRes = await client.conversations.createConversation(conversationParams).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

I tried to post the message first, and immediately update the activity and set the type as `ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation`. However, it doesn't work at all.

```js
const tmpResult = await client.conversations.updateActivity(teamsChannelId, msRes.activityId, {type: ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation})
```

Error form above updateActivity code:

```js
RestError: Unknown activity type
at ...(skipped for paths)

{
    code: 'BadArgument',
    statusCode: 400,
    request: WebResource {
        streamResponseBody: false,
        url: 'https://{service_url}/{channel_id}/activities/{messageActivityId}',
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: HttpHeaders {
            _headersMap: [Object]
        },
        body: '{"type":"endOfConversation"}',
        query: undefined,
        formData: undefined,
        withCredentials: false,
        abortSignal: undefined,
        timeout: 0,
        onUploadProgress: undefined,
        onDownloadProgress: undefined,
        proxySettings: undefined,
        keepAlive: undefined,
        agentSettings: undefined,
        operationSpec: {
            httpMethod: 'PUT',
            path: 'v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId}',
            urlParameters: [Array],
            requestBody: [Object],
            responses: [Object],
            serializer: [Serializer]
        }
    },
    response: {
        body: '{"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Unknown activity type"}}',
        headers: HttpHeaders {
            _headersMap: [Object]
        },
        status: 400
    },
    body: {
        error: {
            code: 'BadArgument',
            message: 'Unknown activity type'
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any method that allows me to do so? Thanks.
It would be better if I could only disable the reply function in Channels from bot programmatically.

---

Update on 2021-06-28:

Simulation of expected behavior on UI:
[image]

Simulation of actual behavior on UI:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've not actually tested this property myself, but it seems like it should handle what you need: In the Teams app manifest, there is a "NotificationOnly" setting on the bot, which means it should not allow users to converse with it (i.e. "reply"). See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notification-only

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice! I tried to add `"isNotificationOnly": true` in the bot section of my app manifest, it works well in individual chat which the user cannot send any message to the bot. 

However, if the bot is posting a message to channels, the user still can click the reply button on the UI to write down their reply message. Is there any alternative solution that could disable the user from clicking the reply button of the bot's message in channels?

Comment: Do you definitely need to have this bot work in both personal + team scopes? Those sound like quite different scenarios. I ask because, if you really only need this capability inside a Team, then webhooks might even be better (they're more simple than bots anyway, and don't really deal with replies)

Comment: Yes, I might need both. I still keep the personal conversation because I want to have a message client that allows the users to update the bot service URL. Anyways, thanks for your suggestions, I will take a look at the webhooks first!

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Please consider upvoting or marking as answer if you feel the advice has been useful (helps others with similar questions in future)

Comment: thanks back, and good luck with this. Just post another question if you get stuck with anything related.